# How to find the average amount of time somebody won a race by Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics

So, as seen in the dataframe, there's 3 races. I want to find the time difference between 1st and second place for each race, then the output would be the average that each runner would win each race by.

```
import pandas as pd

# initialise data of lists.
data = {'Name':['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C'], 'RaceNumber': 
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'PlaceWon':['First', 'Second', 'First', 'Second', 'First', 'Second'], 'TimeRanInSec':[100, 98, 66, 60, 75, 70]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the output.
print(df)
```

In this case, The output would be a data frame that outputs A won races by an average of 3.5 sec. B won by an average of 6 sec.

I imagine this could be done by grouping by RaceNumber and then subtracting TimeRanInSec. But unsure how to get the average of each Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two groupby operations, one to get the winning margin for each race, and then one to get the average winning margin for each person.

For a general solution, I would first define a function that calculates the winning margin from a list of times (for one race). Then you can apply that function to the times in each race group and join the resulting winning margins to the dataframe of all the winners. Then it's easy to get the desired averages:

```py
def winning_margin(times):
    times = list(times)
    winner = min(times)
    times.remove(winner)
    return min(times) - winner

winning_margins = df[['RaceNumber', 'TimeRanInSec']] \
                    .groupby('RaceNumber').agg(winning_margin)
winning_margins.columns = ['margin']

winners = df.loc[df.PlaceWon == 'First', :]
winners = winners.join(winning_margins, on='RaceNumber')

avg_margins = winners[['Name', 'margin']].groupby('Name').mean()
avg_margins
```

```
      margin
Name    
A     3.5
B     6.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer... my only question would be what would be the argument for min in 'return min(times) - winner' as it is an empty sequence?

Comment: The idea is that `times` initially contains the times of all the runners in one race. Then we remove the winning time, so `min(times)` will then be the second best time.

Comment: For Some reason, cannot for the life of me get this to work ... :(

Comment: The code does work for me with the `df` you provided. Do you get any error messages, or what exactly does not work? Or is the real dataframe substantially different from the simple example above?

Comment: Coming back to your comment. Wanted to work it out. In my actual dataset, there were snags. In some instances, to continue this example, only 1 person ran in a race, therefore when you remove the winning time, there was nothing left in the list to set as "second place". Once I removed those instances, your code worked perfectly. Thank you again.